# Getting identity from another method in the same class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class

Into class I get logged user like

```
public static GetUserById_Result GetUser(string userId)
        {
            GetUserById_Result user = new GetUserById_Result();

            try
            {
                using (EF.SSMA oContext = new EF.SSMA())
                {
                    user = oContext.GetUserById(userId).FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return user;
        }
```

So it runs fine. But in the same class I want to acces user value into another method

```
 public static List<GetUsers_Result> SelectAll()
        {
            List<GetUsers_Result> lstResult = new List<GetUsers_Result>();


            try
            {
                using (EF.SSMA oContext = new EF.SSMA())
                {

                    lstResult = oContext.GetUsers().Where().ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return lstResult;
        }
```

What I need to do to achieve that?, into controller is really simple I just do this:

```
        var users = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            GetUserById_Result currentUser = UserClass.GetUser(users);
            var role = currentUser.BranchOfficeId;
```

But how can I acces it in the same class' I try to call GetUserId with

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

but it just mark HttpContext in red and say "Cannot resolve symbol 'HttpContext'"

My target is to call only users who BranchOfficeId = user.BranchOfficeId

Help is very appreciated. Regards

Comment: I don't get why you use two different DTOs one for single and other one for the list. Aren't they the same in fact?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question well, make sure that you already installed the package `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` and add `using System.Web`, then use directely `User.Identity.GetUserId()`

Comment: and I can´t just get return of getUser method to SelectAll method that already are in the same class?

Comment: sorry i can't understand your question :/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can do this in the controller is because `Controller` has an `HttpContext` property, which has been created with the details of the current request, including the identity of the current user.

If you want to access the user from another class, you need to pass the user as an argument to your method.  As an example:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod(IPrincipal user)
    {
        // Whatever you need
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
var someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.SomeMethod(HttpContext.User);
```

However, if you're only interested in the user's name, then you can actually just pass a string instead:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeMethod(string username)
    {
        // Whatever you need
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
var someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.SomeMethod(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
```